# SQL: Flagging New Values; Creating Date Ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use SQL to create a Start Date & End Date to show each time there is change in the value of the Type column (ordered by ID). I need to group all contiguous encounters of the same Type into the same date range, but reflect each time the Type has changed.

```
Current Data Format:
ID  Type    Date
1   A   1/1/2018
1   A   1/20/2018
1   B   3/15/2018
2   C   1/10/2018
2   A   1/12/2018
2   C   4/19/2018
3   B   2/10/2018
3   B   3/9/2018
3   D   5/1/2018

Desired Format:
ID  Type Start Date End Date 
1   A   1/1/2018    3/14/2018
1   B   3/15/2018   12/31/9999
2   C   1/10/2018   1/11/2018
2   A   1/12/2018   4/18/2018
2   C   4/19/2018   12/31/9999
3   B   2/10/2018   4/30/2018
3   D   5/1/2018    12/31/9999
```

I would be happy to share the code that I have tried (different index types, flags, etc.), but honestly nothing has even gotten close to the desired format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This produces the output you are looking for. Notice how I posted a table and sample data in a consumable format. You should consider something similar in the future. It makes it really easy for others to help.

This will not work unless you are sql server 2012 or newer. If you are on an older version this can still be accomplished it just becomes more challenging.

```
declare @Something table
(
    ID int
    , SomeType char(1)
    , SomeDate date
)

insert @Something values
(1, 'A', '1/1/2018')
, (1, 'A', '1/20/2018')
, (1, 'B', '3/15/2018')
, (2, 'C', '1/10/2018')
, (2, 'A', '1/12/2018')
, (2, 'C', '4/19/2018')
, (3, 'B', '2/10/2018')
, (3, 'B', '3/9/2018')
, (3, 'D', '5/1/2018')
;

with groups as
(
    select *
        , MyGroup = Lag(SomeType, 1) over(partition by ID order by SomeDate)
    from @Something s
)

select g.ID
    , Type = g.SomeType
    , StartDate = g.SomeDate
    , EndDate = isnull(dateadd(day, -1, Lead(SomeDate, 1) over(partition by ID order by SomeDate)), '99991231')
from groups g
where g.SomeType <> isnull(g.MyGroup, '')
```

Comment: If this works for you consider marking it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (ID  INT, Type VARCHAR(10),   [Date] DATE)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES
(1, 'A', '1/1/2018'),
(1, 'A', '1/20/2018'),
(1, 'B', '3/15/2018'),
(2, 'C', '1/10/2018'),
(2, 'A', '1/12/2018'),
(2, 'C', '4/19/2018'),
(3, 'B', '2/10/2018'),
(3, 'B', '3/9/2018'),
(3, 'D', '5/1/2018')


;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Type, GRP ORDER BY [Date]) AS F 
    FROM (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID, [Date]) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Type ORDER BY ID, [Date]) GRP
        FROM @MyTable
    ) AS T
)
, CTE2 AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID, [Date]) RN, * FROM CTE T1
    WHERE F= 1 
)
SELECT  T1.ID, T1.Type, T1.[Date] [Start Date], ISNULL(DATEADD(DAY,-1,T2.[Date]),'99991231') [End Date]
FROM CTE2 AS T1
    LEFT JOIN CTE2 AS T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID AND T1.RN = T2.RN - 1
ORDER BY T1.ID, T1.[Date]
```

Result:

```
ID          Type       Start Date End Date
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1           A          2018-01-01 2018-03-14
1           B          2018-03-15 9999-12-31
2           C          2018-01-10 2018-01-11
2           A          2018-01-12 2018-04-18
2           C          2018-04-19 9999-12-31
3           B          2018-02-10 2018-04-30
3           D          2018-05-01 9999-12-31
```